# No se confía en este certificado

Tags: c#, windows-forms, clickonce

No se confía en este certificado de raíz de CA porque no figura en el almacén de entidades de certificación raíz de confianza

mi pregunta es como puedo crear o donde puedo adquirir un certificado para firmar el manifiestos de mi aplicación de escritorio, y  poder distribuirla sin que un antivirus me la bloquee ??

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.